# Why is string comparison after prompting user for a string/option not working as expected?

Tags: batch-file

Is this the proper way to write these lines of batch code with the exceptions of spaces and unneeded percent signs?

```
:name
cls
echo now that we've got your color figured out, what about your name?
echo simply type the name you want for your character into the space below
echo (6 char max)
echo.
set /p %player% =

cls
echo so you want your name to be %player% ?
echo.
echo 1) yes
echo 2) no

set /p %namechoice% =
if %namechoice% == 1 goto check
if %namechoice% == 2 goto name


:check
if /I %player% == %username% (goto gamestart) else goto suprise

:suprise
```

The player name is not output after batch user entered it.

And the string comparisons with `check` and `name` are also not working.

The command line `if %namechoice% == 1 goto check` results in break of batch file execution with error message:

> goto was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Lose the spaces around the `=` sign.  So your code says `%namechoice%<space>==<space>1` which will never be true. After a block use `Goto :eof` so code lower down won't be run.

Comment: No.  You do not use percent symbols when assigning a variable only when referencing it.  You also need to remove the space before the equals symbol in your SET statement.  `set /p namechoice=` Also, my best practice is to use quotes around my comparisons and no spaces before or after the equals symbols.. `if "%namechoice%"=="1" goto check`

Comment: You could also use an `if`/`else` construct in your `:check` section: `if "%player%"=="%username%" (goto gamestart) else goto suprise` (the parentheses are mandatory here, because without them, the statement does not know when the conditional part before `else` ends); use the quotation marks for such string comparisons to avoid trouble in case of empty strings or special characters; in addition, consider to use `if /I "%player%"=="%username%"` to do a case-insensitive comparison, particularly because you are checking user input... see this: [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake is a simple syntax issue:

**Environment variables are defined with just specifying the variable name without percent signs and with no space character before the equal sign.**

So wrong is

```
set /p %player% =
set /p %namechoice% =
```

because those two lines are expanded during preprocessing phase before really executing the command **SET** to

```
set /p  =
set /p  =
```

in case of environment variables `player` and `namechoice` are not already defined. See [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for details about how to define an environment variable right. It explains also why the space character left to equal sign on variable definition becomes part of the variable name which is nearly always unwanted by batch file writer.

Such simple syntax issues can be easily seen on running a batch file **without** `@echo off` at top of the batch file or with this line modified to `@echo on` or commented out with `::@echo off` (invalid label) or `rem @echo off` (remark command) from within a command prompt window by entering name of the batch file with full path in double quotes instead of double clicking on the batch file.

What makes the difference?

1. With `@echo off` the command lines are **not** printed into the console window after preprocessing (expanding environment variables) before really executing them. This is the wanted behavior when batch file development finished. But during development and testing of a batch file it is definitely better to get displayed what is really executed by Windows command interpreter to find coding mistakes.
2. On double clicking a batch file `cmd.exe` is started to execute the batch file with option `/C` for closing the console window automatically when batch file execution terminated independent on success or error of execution. This makes it not possible to see for example syntax errors output by Windows command interpreter which result in an immediate exit of batch file execution. Therefore it is advisable during batch file development to run it from within a manually opened command prompt window as in this case `cmd.exe` is started with option `/K` to keep the console window open even after batch processing finished, except the batch file uses command `exit` without parameter `/B`. This makes it possible to see also the error message of an error which caused an unexpected exit of batch processing.

Later when batch file works as expected, the first line can be `@echo off` again and of course the batch file can be started with a double click. But during batch file development it is definitely better to always run the batch file from within a command prompt window. The up/down arrow keys can be used to scroll through the list of entered strings which makes it also possible to re-enter for example the player name easily again.

Here is the batch code rewritten with several improvements and comments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define a too long player name before prompting the user for the player
rem name. This too long player name is kept in case of user hits just the
rem key RETURN or ENTER without entering anything at all. Then test for
rem entered name has not more than 6 characters. Delayed expansion is used
rem as the user could enter characters like " ! % ... which would in further
rem batch code execution result in exiting batch processing because of syntax
rem error or in unexpected behavior on referencing player name with expansion
rem before running the command.

:PromptForName
cls
echo Now that we've got your color figured out, what about your name?
echo Simply type the name you want for your character into the space
echo below (6 char max).
echo/
set "Player=No name entered"
set /P "Player=Player name: "
if not "!Player:~6!" == "" goto PromptForName

echo/
echo/
echo    1) yes
echo    2) no
echo/
choice /C:12 /N "So you want your name to be !player!? "
if errorlevel 2 goto PromptForName

if /I "!player!" == "%USERNAME%" goto GameStart

echo Surprise
endlocal
goto :EOF

:GameStart
echo/
echo Okay !Player!, let's play^^!

rem Wait 3 seconds using PING instead of TIMEOUT before exiting the
rem batch file because the command TIMEOUT does not exist on Windows XP.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul

endlocal
```

The comment at top explains why the environment variable `Player` is defined with value `No name entered`. The batch user has the freedom to hit just <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without entering anything at all or hits by mistake one of those 2 keys before entering a name. In this case the environment variable `Player` is either still not defined if not defined before, or it keeps its current value if already defined before. It is not good if the user enters nothing and the environment variable `Player` is not defined in this case. Therefore the player name is predefined with an invalid name.

The length of the entered player name is also tested on being too long.

And the string entered by the user could contain batch syntax critical characters like a double quote, a percent sign, a redirection operator character (angle bracket, pipe), an ampersand, or with delayed expansion enabled an exclamation mark. To prevent an exit of batch processing caused by a syntax error by entered player name on using environment variable expansion before command line execution, the environment variable `Player` is referenced everywhere with usage of delayed expansion enabled at top of the batch file.

For printing a blank line it is better to use `echo/` instead of `echo.` because `echo.` could fail and is a little bit slower because of Windows command interpreter searches for a file matching the pattern `echo.*` as documented in DosTips forum article [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774).

The command **CHOICE** is much better than `set /P VariableName=Prompt text` if the user has to enter specific keys. The command **CHOICE** does not allow that the user enters something not wanted by batch file writer and is therefore much safer for a choice menu.

The account name of current user referenced with `%USERNAME%` could contain also a space character. Therefore it is highly recommended to enclose the entire string containing `%USERNAME%` always in double quotes.

`"%USERNAME%"` on right side of a string comparison requires that the string on left side is also enclosed in double quotes because command **IF** compares the two strings with including the double quotes.

For that reason the condition

```
if /I !player! == "%USERNAME%"
```

would be only true if the batch file user would have entered the player name with double quotes which is very unlikely. The double quotes must be also used on left side.

The number of space characters around the two compared strings enclosed in double quotes or not enclosed in double quotes does not matter.

Executing in a command prompt window the following batch file

```
@echo on
@setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@set "Player=<|>"
if /I "!Player!"=="%SystemRoot%" echo Strings are equal.
if /I "!Player!"  ==  "%WinDir%" echo Strings are equal.
if /I   "!Player!" ==  "%Player%" echo Strings are equal.
if /I "!Player!"==   "!Player!" echo Strings are equal.
if   /I   !Player!  ==  !Player! echo Strings are equal.
@endlocal
```

results in the output

```
if /I "!Player!" == "C:\WINDOWS" echo Strings are equal.

if /I "!Player!" == "C:\WINDOWS" echo Strings are equal.

if /I "!Player!" == "<|>" echo Strings are equal.
Strings are equal.

if /I "!Player!" == "!Player!" echo Strings are equal.
Strings are equal.

if /I !Player! == !Player! echo Strings are equal.
Strings are equal.
```

It can be seen that the space characters around comparison operator `==` do not matter on execution of command **IF**. The Windows command processor formats the command lines pretty before executing the **IF** commands.

But a space character in a string to compare requires the usage of double quotes because otherwise an exit of batch processing occurs most likely because of a syntax error on batch file execution.

**Note:** The equal operator `==` of command **IF** is handled different than the assignment operator `=` of command **SET**. Don't mix them.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ping /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And see also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul`.