# Batch file for data copy by user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following MS Windows batch file code:

```
@echo off
cd\
dir/s *.docx *.xlsx *.ppt *.docx
SET /p input= %data% "
copy "%data%" C:\abc\
pause
```

This command shows all 4 types of extension list all over drives, but I want to take input from user and then copy to the desired location.

What am I missing?

Comment: There are only 3 file types one is doubled. I guess the error stems from using `%data%` instead of `%input%` If the var data isn't previously assigned a value it is empty.

Comment: Run it after changing `@echo off` to `@echo ON`. Apply http://ss64.com/nt/ as reference. Unclear what is `%data%` and you do not _use_ variable `%input%` (post a [mcve]).

Comment: `set /? |find /i "set /p"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main mistake is assigning the string entered by the user of the batch file to environment variable `input` but referencing on command `copy` the environment variable `data` which is not defined at all and therefore `%data%` is replaced twice before execution of the command line by nothing.

What about using this batch code?

```
@echo off
rem The next 2 commands are commented out as not needed for this task.
rem cd \
rem dir /s *.doc *.docx *.xlsx *.ppt

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:UserPrompt
echo/
echo Enter the file name with complete path or drag and drop
echo the file to copy from Windows Explorer over this window.
echo/
set "FileName=""
set /p "FileName=Enter file name: "
echo/

rem Remove all double quotes from entered string.
set "FileName=!FileName:"=!"

rem Has the user entered any file name at all?
if "!FileName!" == "" goto UserPrompt

rem Does the file really exist?
if exist "!FileName!" goto CopyFile

echo Error: The specified file does not exist.
echo/
goto UserPrompt

:CopyFile
copy "!FileName!" C:\abc\
echo/
endlocal
pause
```

Read the answer on [Why is string comparison after prompting user for a string/option not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444623/3074564) for an explanation on all the extra code used here.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thanx alot  ,It us very helpful ..you are a genius